# Everything on hard drive suddenly vanished without explanation, but the drive seems otherwise functional

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a new desktop that I built a few months ago that has [a four-year-old WD hard drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q82PIQ) and a two-year-old drive. I had set it up so that the newer drive had Windows and most of my files on it while the older drive had my music library, some movies and games, and a backup of all of my documents. About a month ago, I installed some new case fans and, in the process, I temporarily unplugged my hard drive (while the computer was off of course - I took all the necessary precautions) for wire management. I plugged it back in, and didn't really think anything of it. At around that time, however, I noticed that my older hard drive wasn't showing up in Windows Explorer anymore but I didn't really have time to check into it (I had just started college) and I'm finally getting a chance to now.

That drive doesn't show up in Windows Explorer at all but it does show up in Disk Management. That screen shows the following: 
[image]

Any idea what happened? Is there any way to recover my files?

I have:
Windows 7 Ultimate x64
Custom-built desktop

EDIT: The music and games and stuff used to be on "Disc 1", the 465.71 GB of what is now showing as unallocated space.

Comment: Which is the partition that isn't behaving as you think it should?  Is it the one showing 465.71 GB unallocated?  What do learn by right-clicking and poking around through properties or by trying to assign a drive letter?

Comment: I get this when I right click and select "Properties": http://puu.sh/17n4H

Comment: @Nicole, I get this when I right click and select "Properties": puu.sh/17n4H (sorry for commenting twice with this - I couldn't figure out how to tag you at first and then by the time I realized it had been more than 5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some info from sector zero or MBR (the part which keeps info about hard drive and file system) has been injured/removed/changed.
Try [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsm/g/masterbootrec.htm).